# How to create a keyboard for other languages using Cordova, Ionic framework?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, custom-keyboard, soft-keyboard

I'm building an app in Ethiopia and I have to integrate Amharic language deeply. How can I create a keyboard with Amharic font on Apache Cordova using Ionic framework?

Comment: I don't think it's a really good idea to try to create a keyboard. Android apps use the OS keyboard, so if the app is installed on de device configured with Amharic language, the app will automatically use the OS Amharic keyboard.

Comment: @QuickFix Can I somehow make keyboard in HTML CSS, and disable the original keyboard? I don't have much experience with Cordova

Comment: yes you can do that. I've done that long time ago when  I needed a special keyboard. You'll have to manage the events yourself and prevent the OS keyboard to show when the inputs get the focus (sorry I don't remember how I dit this). You don't need cordova to test this. You should see the same behaviour if you debug in chrome on the device.